# Unsigned int values gives negative number above the halfway point of max byte value?

Tags: avr, uart, serial, atmega328p, variable

MCU: Atemga328P: Datasheet:https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf

Note: I am a beginner :)

Considering a 2 byte `unsigned int` data type, where 65535 is the max value and 32767 in the halfway point.

Problem: `unsigned int num;` in the below code yields negative numbers on serial monitor for `unsigned int num` values above 32767 even though it is an `unsigned` variable.

Examples: `unsigned int num = 65534` shows -2 on the serial monitor and `unsigned int num = 32768` shows -32768 on the serial monitor.

Note: I am using USB connection provided by Arduino board for UART communication.

```
#include <avr/io.h> // header file file for input output pins
#include <util/delay.h> // header file for delay.
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUD 9600
#define BRC  ((F_CPU/16/BAUD)-1)

void uarttrasnmitinteger(unsigned int num,  char*snum, int delay);
void uarttransmitenable(void);

char snum[20];
unsigned int num = -65534;  

int main (void)
{
    uarttransmitenable();

    while (1)
    {
        uarttrasnmitinteger(num, snum, 1000);

    }
}
void uarttransmitenable(void){ // Enables UART transmission
    UBRR0H = (BRC >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BRC;

    UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ00);
}

void uarttrasnmitinteger(unsigned int num,  char*snum, int delay){ 
    itoa(num, snum, 10);  //Converts integer to string
    unsigned int i;
        for (i=0; i< strlen(snum); i++)
        {
            while (( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0))  == 0){};
            UDR0 = (char)snum[i];  //outputs to serial monitor
        }
        _delay_ms(delay);
}
```

Comment: Bytes sent across the wire have no meaning, you need to convert it on the serial side to unsigned int.

Comment: What Ron Beyer said. And: what are you trying to do here: unsigned int num = -65534; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the `itoa()` function. Its parameter is a normal signed integer, so your unsigned int is being coerced to a signed int.

Comment: The function you want is utoa()

Comment: Thanks, @Kartman

Comment: That worked fine! Thanks